# How to extract a route params using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have some strings that look like any of these:

```
/challenges/:challenge_id/submissions/:id
/challenges/:challenge_id/submissions
/api/v1/submissions/:id
/submissions
```

The strings starting with ':' and ended by a '/' or a blank line are Rails route params. ie: 'challenge_id' and ':id'

I'd like to do 2 things with this string

- extract the route param variables into a ruby array for later use
- replace those param variables by '1'

So output for the first example:

```
arr = [':challenge_id',':id']    
new string = '/challenges/1/submissions/1'
```

I've tried this, but it is matching everything

```
/[:[a-z*]]/
```

I'm testing in http://rubular.com/ as I need this to run in Ruby code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = []
"/challenges/:challenge_id/submissions/:id".gsub(/:[^\/]+/){|s| arr.push(s); "1"}
# => "/challenges/1/submissions/1"
arr
# => [":challenge_id", ":id"]
```

Comment: would vote this up twice if I could. Concise, but perfectly readable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match *params* that may have capital letters in them, then you can use `\w` shorthand:

```
:\w+
```

This will match all params including the ones with capital letters.

```
# For example:
/challenges/:Challenge_id/submissions/:ID
```

**Ruby code:**

```
string = "/challenges/:challenge_id/submissions/:id"

# To get a matching params array
string.scan(/:\w+/)              #  => [":challenge_id", ":id"]

# To replace them with "1"s
string.gsub(/:\w+/, '1')         #  => "/challenges/1/submissions/1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be this:

> (:[a-z]*)

() is for the capture group.

"*" should be outside the character class.

To improve your current regex, you could do this:

> (\/:[a-z]+)

Add a forward slashes "/", so not to match ":" in the middle of the param variables and change the "*" operator to "+", so not to match ":" alone.